# Terminal will not open in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

OS is linux.

Opening the terminal produces this error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "bash" is not a file of a symlink.
```

The path to bash is correct in settings.json and the `$PATH` variable.

This is Visual Studio Code version 1.57.1. rolling back to an earlier version fixes the issue, so I made a bug report.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As jebeaudet said in his comment, edit the file

**`~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`**

and add this line

`"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {"bash": {"path": "/bin/bash"}},`

(in my case has occurs when upgrading from v1.55 to v1.60)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, terminal.integrated.shell.linux wasn't set in settings.json which was causing the issue

Comment: `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",`

Comment: This is now a deprecated variable and has been replaced by `"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {"bash": {"path": "/bin/bash"}}`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem since I upgraded to 1.57.1.
The problem shows up when I launch VSCODE from Gnome desktop or from the terminal without following the command code with a dot.
However if I enter "code ." then there is no problem.

I could not find "terminal.integrated.shell.linux" in the settings to set the path to the shell bash command.